# Converting website from running on IIS 6.0 to iis 7.0 using native integrated pipeline mode on Server 2008 64 bit

Tags: iis-7, 64-bit, integrated-pipeline-mode

**Summary**

To get my site running smoothly on a **64bit** server platform, using **IIS 7.0 Integrated pipeline mode**, what are the things I would need to fix in order for this to work.

**Some more detail**

I am aware of, that if a assembly uses PInvoke and I have a reference to such a assembly in my project, the error message I will get will probably be very vague and obscure.

- How do I go about finding these assemblies?
- If I look at a dll, with reflector, and there is no PInvokes, would this be sufficient to assume that the dll, would be fine in a 64 bit environment?

Any specific suggestions on how to check that my site is fully 64 bit compatible?  Would compiling it as AnyCPU be sufficient to ensure that it will run correctly in Integrated pipeline mode?

Thanks
Rihan

Comment: Are you concerned with the IIS6 to IIS7 conversion or primarily concerned with running on the 64bit platform?

Comment: The IIS 6 to IIS 7 conversion works well, except the site breaks on some arb "is not a valid Win32 application. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700C1)" I am assuming that this is probably related to bad dll's that we use in the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have found the offending dll, buy a process of elimination.  So sadly I cant offer a more "scientific" approach.

What I have learned through this process:

- Be careful when selecting 3rd party libraries
- Especially when it is just a "proof of concept"
- Before you know it, that code is in production, and you spend a week trying to find that one library that is causing problems.

You probably wont have to deal with this issues, but developers that come after you will have less respect for you.